# Bootstrap DropDown Menu Not Working in Safari on iPhone

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I am using below bootstap code for drop down menu. I found that its working properly with Chrome & Firefox but when we use in Safari on iOS it doesn't work.

```
<div class="crypt-mobile-menu">
            <ul class="crypt-heading-menu" role="menu">
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="/">Exchange</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="OrderBook">Orders</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="TradeBook">TradeBook</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="Transactions">Transactions</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="Balance">Balance</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><asp:HyperLink role="menuitem" ID="menuUnlockMobile" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/UnlockWallet">Unlock Wallet</asp:HyperLink></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="https://urlzs.com/FyPs1" target="_blank">Submit Token</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1puQjsJLjQ25JZn8rcj" target="_blank">Airdrop</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="https://medium.com/" target="_blank">Blog</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="AboutUs">About Us</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
```

Thanks in advance